# Get any not null value of other fileds in aggregations

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to aggregate on some fields and get any not null value on others. To be more precise the query looks something like:

```
SELECT id, any_value(field1), any_value(field2) FROM mytable GROUP BY ID
```

and the columns are like:

```
ID  | field1 | field 2
-----------------
id  | null   | 3
id  | 1      | null
id  | null   | null
id  | 2      | 4
```

and the output can be like `(id, 1,4)` or `(id,2,4)` or ... but not something like `(id, 1, null)`

I can't find in the docs if `any_value()` is guaranteed to return a not null row if there is one (although it did so in my experiments) or may return a row with `null` value even if there are some not null values.

Does `any_value()` perform the task I described? If not what way to you suggest for doing it?

Comment: I cannot follow your question.  You have `id` in the query, but not in the sample data.  You have three columns in your output, but it is confusing.

Comment: I edited the my question, hope it's clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of a guess, but have you tried:

```
SELECT id, MIN(field1), MAX(field2)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id;
```

This will ignore `NULL` values return different values from the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analyatical functions as well.

Below is the query (SQL server):

```
select id, field1, field2 
  from (select id, field1, field2, row_number() 
    over (partition by id order by isnull(field1, 'ZZZ') asc, isnull(field2, 'ZZZ') asc) as RNK from mytable) aa 
  where aa.RNK = 1;
```

This will return only one row, you can change the order in `order by` clause if you are looking for maximun value in any column.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by aggregating to array with 'ignore nulls' specified and taking the first element of the resulting array. Unlike MIN/MAX solution, you can use it with structs

```
SELECT
  id,
  ARRAY_AGG(field1 IGNORE NULLS LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)],
FROM
  mytable
GROUP BY
  id
```